# Java process exec won't work on adb push

Tags: java, android, shell

When using

```
    Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(PATH+"adb push /home/user/test.txt /storage/sdcard0/Documents");
    p.waitFor();
```

nothing is pushed on phone, no errors were raised. Command finishes instantly no matter how large file is being sent. The funny thing is that the same code with different commands like "adb shell ls", "adb devices", "adb connect" etc. executes without problems. Also the push commands works perfectly when fired in terminal.

Reading output with

```
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
```

Only gets null.
PATH variable is set to sdk's platform-tools directory.

Am i missing something?

Comment: My usual advice for using runtime.exec() is to do everything in a shell script (or batch file if on Windows), and then simply invoke the shell script from exec(). If you need to get more complex than that, consider using ProcessBuilder

Comment: I'v tried with ProcessBuilder and shell script but got the same result. When i try to use any other command in script it works and i get the output. Also adb help command acts the same, it just finishes instantly with null output.

Answer (score 0):

If value of PATH is a valid path and not something like `/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin`, then perhaps you just missed adding another slash to separate the directory from the command:

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(PATH+"/adb push /home/user/test.txt /storage/sdcard0/Documents");
```

You can also try to use an absolute path to just verify that the path is really not the problem to it:

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/to/adb push /home/user/test.txt /storage/sdcard0/Documents");
```

Comment: Na, the PATH is valid. The same setup works with adb shell, adb devices, and running the shell script from that directory works fine. The only problem is adb push that just doesn't start to do anything. And in the meantime i found that adb help acts the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "adb help" sends it's output to stderr.
So you need to look at the process's errorStream in addition to it's inputStream.

I'm guessing that in your case, "adb push" is encountering an error, so output is again going to stderr.

Comment: It happens to me too. The error stream of the process contains the exact content of `adb help` - no errors, only helppage